# Require_once Errors When Moved Host

Tags: php, apache, hosting, php-5.3

I moved my site to a new host, and it's not loading.    (Have not had this problem before,  on my local server, or 2 previous hosts).

The first line of my index.php is:

```
require_once("includes/initialize.php");
```

Then the initialize should load includes/config.php:

```
 defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
 defined('SITE_ROOT')? null : 
    define('SITE_ROOT', '/webspace/httpdocs'.DS.'sitename.com');
 defined('LIB_PATH') ? null : define('LIB_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes');
 require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'config.php');
```

These errors are in the log file...

> PHP Warning: 
>   require_once(/webspace/httpdocs/sitename.com/includes/config.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /usr/local/pem/vhosts/253981/webspace/httpdocs/sitename.com/includes/initialize.php
>   on line 11
>
> PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/webspace/httpdocs/sitename.com/includes/config.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in
>   /usr/local/pem/vhosts/253981/webspace/httpdocs/sitename.com/includes/initialize.php
>   on line 11

Both hosts are using PHP 5.3.
Here are the main differences that I can see (from phpinfo).

Old host:

- PHP Version:           5.3.22
- Server API:            CGI/FastCGI
- Loaded Configuration File:   /usr/local/lib/php.ini
- include_path:        .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php

New host:

- PHP Version:                  5.3.3
- Server API:                   Apache 2.0 Handler
- Loaded Configuration File:    /etc/php.ini
- include_path:                 .:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php

My knowledge here is limited.  I don't know how these settings would actually be causing the errors listed above. 
Are there other settings I should be looking for?

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: can you show the line that includes config.php. And are you sure the file exists?

Comment: updated to include that code. Yes, the file definitely exists.

Comment: Are you sure "/usr/local/pem/vhosts/253981/webspace/httpdocs/sitename.com/includes/initialize.php" this file exists?

Comment: @TroyCheng The file exists relative to /webspace/httpdocs/sitename.com/includes/ in my FTP.

Comment: Pay attention to this prefix: "/usr/local/pem/vhosts/253981/", set the base path correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be setting the incorrect basepath

`/webspace` should be `/usr/local/pem/vhosts/253981/webspace`

```
defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : define('SITE_ROOT', '/usr/local/pem/vhosts/253981/webspace'.DS.'sitename.com');
```